# Recovering projects deleted by discarding SVN location

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

Earlier I began work on a project that was not connected to SVN. So, first things first, I connected it up using Subversive and "Attach projects". Subversive kept giving me authentication errors, but the correct versioning appeared on the files, so I assumed it had attached.

I then did my work in the project, writing a blog post.

I then wanted to commit it back. The authentication errors persisted so I could not commit the work. I noticed that the connection to SVN was actually to a parent path of the module I wanted to commit to - this would cause the authentication errors. The path I was connected to was:

```
http://mysvnserver.com/svn/
```

It should have been:

```
http://mysvnserver.com/svn/blog-projects
```

The module was chosen on the basis of the existing SVN data I think. There are multiple projects involved, so maybe one of the modules was different and it chose the nearest common parent?

So I discarded the SVN location and went back to re-attach the projects to the correct module.

... but my projects were gone.

No sign of them on the filesystem.

No way of restoring from local history.

Was this supposed to happen? I'd assume not. I've just found this which seems to be the same problem: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=376798

Is there any way of restoring this so I haven't just lost a load of work?

Comment: What does "discarded the SVN location" mean? Did you delete it in Eclipse only? Delete content from the repository? Delete the repository itself? As long as you haven't deleted the repository, anything that had been previously committed to the repository is still there & can be retrieved if you can read the repository log.

Comment: Right click the repository in the _SVN Repositories_ view, click _Discard Location_. Obviously I still have everything in the repository, it's the hour or two's uncommitted work I'm worried about.

Comment: If it's uncommitted, and you can't find it on your local disk, it's almost certainly gone. Subversion doesn't have a record of it.

Comment: Agree, just wondered if Eclipse could do some magic from its local history. A `find .metadata -name "*my-project-name*"` doesn't find anything though :-(